# If $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and $f$ is continuous, is $\{f(a_n)\}$ a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: continuity, cauchy-sequences

> If $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and $f$ is continuous, is $\{f(a_n)\}$ a Cauchy sequence?

It's easy to do it on some certain domain of $f$. But the problem is How to disprove it is $f$ is $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$

Comment: If $f$ is uniformly continuous, then yes. Otherwise not necessarily.

Comment: Let $a_n=1/n$ and $f(x)=1/x.$ Then $f$ is continuous on the positive reals and the sequence is Cauchy. The sequence with terms $f(a_n)$ does not converge, so is not Cauchy. Now see Ethan's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, it is true.

Since $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy in $\Bbb R$ implies $\{a_n\}$ converges and hence by continuity of $f$ , $f(a_n)$ is also converges  and hence Cauchy!

Comment: Yes, our professor set a trick for us. Thank you!